# @Html.DropDownListFor class with collection problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a viewModel class 'SomeDataViewMode' that class have 'List Schools' object that is filled with 'School' objects. School obejct has properties SchoolID and Name.
In my view (Razor) I added:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.ScoolId, new SelectList(Model.Schools), "Select some school")
```

But all I got is drop down list with:

```
MyProject.Domain.Entities.School
```

How to get values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either add a `ToString()` method to the `School` class, or use LINQ to create `SelectListItem`s with `Text`s and `Value`s:

```
new SelectList(Model.Schools.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.Name, Value = s.SchoolId }))
```

**EDIT**: Your code is needlessly complex.
You can write

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Schools, new SelectList(list, "SchoolId", "Name"))
```

Comment: I tried with '@Html.DropDownListFor(new SelectList(Model.Schools.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.Name, Value = s.SchoolId})))'. But it requires second parameter.

Comment: No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 argument. But thanks to your idea I got this code working.  @{
    List<MyProject.Domain.Entities.School> list = Model.Schools;
    var schools = new SelectList(list, "SchoolId", "Name");
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Schools, @items)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which property of the School object should be used for Value and which for Text. For example if the `School` model had `Name` and `Id` properties:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    c => c.ScoolId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Schools, "Id", "Name"), 
    "Select some school"
)
```